# The Images doesn't show Correclty with Ajax Loop by cycle or slik js

Tags: jquery, ajax, slick.js

in my document if I directly add images in a div and using cycle or slick js, my slideshow works, but if I add images by ajax the div show array of images and doesn't work.

this is div:

```
<div class="slideshow"></div>
```

by adding images to div the cycle or slick js works:

```
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="images/image1.jpg" />
<img src="images/image2.jpg" />
<img src="images/image3.jpg" />
<img src="images/image4.jpg" />
</div>
```

but in adding the images by ajax the div just show images and no sliding (just array of images):

```
init:
$(".slideshow").slick({}) or $(".slideshow").cycle({});


ajax: 

$.ajax({
url: '/getimages'
}).done(function(data){

$.each(data.images, function(i, image){
$(".slideshow").append(`<img src="images/${image}" />`);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to initialize the slider after the ajax call is done.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/getimages'
}).done(function(data) {
  $.each(data.images, function(i, image) {
    $(".slideshow").append(`<img src="images/${image}" />`);
  });

  $(".slideshow").slick({}) or $(".slideshow").cycle({});
});
``
```

Comment: happy to help :)